# Bad Access In Pointer Allocation

Tags: c, pointers

So I need to make a function that takes a parameter of type `char **`, and makes that point to a string.

I've spent hours on it and I know it's probably a super dumb thing that I'm missing.

Here is my latest attempt:

```c
void magic_string(char ** new_string) {
  char * my_string = (char*) malloc((5+1)*sizeof(char));
  my_string = "abcde";
  new_string = &my_string;
}
```

But when I try to use the `new_string` in the calling function, it is still `null`.

I also tried replacing the last line with `*new_string = my_string` but recieved a bad access exception.

Comment: There are two major problems here and they are both common FAQ. I have linked a duplicate target per problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're only changing the local variable `new_string`, so changes aren't reflected in the calling function.

You want to dereference `new_string` and assign the pointer to that.

```
*new_string = my_string;
```

Also, you're leaking memory by first assigning an allocated memory block to `my_string`, then overwriting that pointer value with a pointer that points to a string literal.  You should instead use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(my_string, "abcde");
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `my_string = "abcde";` overwrites the value of your pointer, rendering the `malloc` call redundant. What you want to do is probably use `strcpy` to copy the string literal into the allocated space instead.
2. `&my_string` is a pointer to *local memory*. So is `new_string`. Neither is available after the function terminates. Instead, you want to assign the value of `my_string` to `*new_string`!
3. `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1. No need to multiply by it.
4. [Don’t cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/1968); assign it directly.

The fixed function looks as follows:

```
void magic_string(char **new_string) {
  char *my_string = malloc(5 + 1);
  strcpy(my_string, "abcde");
  *new_string = my_string;
}
```

And it needs to be called with a pointer, e.g.:

```
char *str;
magic_string(&str);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Super helpful :) Can I just ask in the last calling section why it is called with ```char *str``` and not ```char **str```?

Comment: @user13292868 If you declare `str` as `char**` and call your function as `magic_string(str)`, you are passing an *uninitialised pointer* into your function, and then you are dereferencing that uninitialised pointer (when you execute `*new_string`). That’s illegal. By contrast, in the code I’ve posted, `str` is a local variable so `&str` is a well-defined, initialised pointer to that automatic (stack-allocated) variable, and `*new_string` is dereferencing the pointer, i.e. referring to that stack-allocated variable.